# formatting html attributes in vim

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

Is it possible with vim/plugin to format/beautify html code, breaking the attributes into separate lines automatically, like:

```
<input 
   class="my-class"
   attibute-1="value 1"
   attibute-2="value 2"
/>
```

Comment: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Cleanup_your_HTML or https://www.google.com/#q=vim+html+beautifier

Comment: yes, but they are as default putting the attributes in one line...

Comment: If using a tool for e.g. `formatprg` or `equalprg` than you need to configure the tool properly