# vim indent html tags with attributes on separate lines

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I am writing some html/vue code with vim, but I found the auto-indent functionality not working as expected, especially with nested tags and attributes broken into multiple lines.

I read the [coding standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44944936/indenting-html-tags-on-multiple-lines) agreed upon for long html tags, and I reason it would be nice if vim can support such indentation style.
I found multiple similar questions asked like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22528973/formatting-html-attributes-in-vim), but they don't give satisfactory answers.
I have also tried the [html5 plugin](https://github.com/othree/html5.vim) for vim, but it doesn't seem to help much.

For example, I would like vim to indent like following:

```html
<template>
    <my-tag 
        attr1
        attr2
        attr3>
        <my-sub-tag
            attr1
            attr2
            attr3>
        </my-sub-tag>
    </my-tag>
</template>
```

But currently, when I press `gg=G`, it indents to something like this:

```html
<template>
    <my-tag 
     attr1
     attr2
     attr3>
        <my-sub-tag
      attr1
      attr2
      attr3>
        </my-sub-tag>
    </my-tag>
</template>
```

Is there a relatively quick way to fix it (like a nice plugin), or is it not yet a primary concern for vim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use a plugin for this! When you use `gg=G` the `equalprg` (see [:h 'equalprg'](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27equalprg%27)) is run. When this option is not set it uses the default or builtin equalprg and that is why you see the odd indentation as they're not built for html.

You could use an external program that is more capable of formatting specific file types. For example, for html you could use `html-beautify` (`npm install --global html-beautify`) for css, json and others you use `prettier`

You can do the following to use an external program.

```
:setlocal equalprg=html-beautify -f - -I -s 2
```

newer versions of `prettier` also supports html formatting.

```
:setlocal equalprg=prettier\ --stdin\ --parser=html
```

add this to `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/html.vim` and use the same command `gg=G` for formatting the lines.

Also see `:h 'formatprg'` and the `:h gq` commands.

Comment: OK, I see. `formatprg` is indeed a nice feature. But my concern is that it won't be very portable -- for example, when I use my school machine where I can't install external programs, I can't use this feature properly. (Currently I'm using Vundle to manage my plugins, and that doesn't require privilege to install external program.) Furthermore, the [html-beautify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-beautify) package has been deprecated. Any other suggestions?

Comment: The newer version of `prettier` supports `html` formatting. `setlocal equalprg=prettier\ --stdin\ --parser=html`

Comment: @ Ben Knobble, Busted! :( Edited the answer.

Comment: @Harish I installed [vim-prettier](https://github.com/prettier/vim-prettier) and that worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: The plugin *also installs* prettier and also says: `If using other vim plugin managers or doing manual setup make sure to have prettier installed globally or go to your vim-prettier directory and either do npm install or yarn install`. So, it's not a lot different. Anyway, you could use whatever works for you! Happing vimming!